# Homomorphism from Roots of unity

Tags: group-theory

Prove that every homomorphism from the group $\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\left\{ 0\right\} |\exists n\in\mathbb{N},n>1\mbox{ such that }z^{n}=1\right\}$ with $\cdot$ to a finite group is trivial (The image is $\left\{ 1\right\}$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group you are dealing with is divisible, but there is no finite divisible group (other than the trivial one).

Comment: Don't know the term of divisible group. Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: Let $f$ be such a morphism to a group with $m$ elements and $\omega$ a root of unity. Then $\omega^{1/m}$ is also a root of unity and we get $f(\omega)=f(\omega^{1/m})^m=...$

Comment: To make it clear what i meant: Divisible is just another term for "$\omega^{1/m}$ exists for all $\omega$ and $m$". The homomorphic image of divisible group is divisible. So the image is a finite divisible group, hence trivial.

That's just to understand the concept. Of course my above proof "by hand" works as well.

Answer (score 2):

The group $G$ in your definition is subgroup of $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon |z|=1\}$. If $\varphi$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to a finite group, then $H=\ker(\varphi)$ is a subgroup of finite index in $G$(since $G/ker(\varphi)$ is finite). Let $[G\colon H]=n$. If $xH$ is any coset of $H$, then $x$ has $n$-th root in $\mathbb{C}$ (by Fund. Thm. Alg), say $y^n=x$. Then $xH=y^nH=(yH)^n=H$ the identity element in $G/H$ (since $|G/H|=n$). Hence $H$ has only one coset, i.e. $\ker(\varphi)=G$, homomorphism is trivial.

---

(I have kept one gap; if you can find, try to fill it.)

Comment: Very nice...and exactly the same argument, but in different form, that MooS puts forward *as a comment* below his answer (which by far is, imo, the shortest and most elegant). +1 ,  and the gap is very small (if it is this): one must show that also $\;y\in G\;$ .